# Facebook sharing/like uses root URL instead of page's URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Since a couple of weeks we are facing a strange problem with how URLs to our page are scraped by Facebook. It doesn't make any difference whether the like button on the page is used or the URL is taken from the address bar in the browser and pasted into the "What's new" Box on Facebook itself. It uses the root Page instead of the page linked.

I've looked through other questions, answers but all the solutions posted there are already implemented.

What's funny is, that if I try to share the same article from the development system, the sharing works fine.

The URLs are:

- not working: http://www.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/sport/2013/01/24/jetzt-zahlt-nur-noch-ein-sieg.vn
- working: http://dev.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/sport/2013/01/24/jetzt-zahlt-nur-noch-ein-sieg.vn

Sharing the first URL leads to sharing http://www.vorarlbergernachrichten.at, sharing the second one is ok. The article is the same, the header information (except the URL of course) is the same as well.

Not working:

```
<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/sport/2013/01/24/jetzt-zahlt-nur-noch-ein-sieg.vn' />
<meta property="og:title" content="Jetzt zählt nur noch ein Sieg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/sport/2013/01/24/jetzt-zahlt-nur-noch-ein-sieg.vn" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Erstes Heimspiel in der Quali-Runde für Dornbirn – Znojmo hat man noch nie geschlagen." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/2013/01/Bis-jetzt-konnten-die-Znojmo-Cracks-Luci.jpg" /><meta name="description" content="Erstes Heimspiel in der Quali-Runde für Dornbirn – Znojmo hat man noch nie geschlagen." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Jetzt,zählt,nur,noch,ein,Sieg" />
```

Working:

```
<link rel='canonical' href='http://dev.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/sport/2013/01/24/jetzt-zahlt-nur-noch-ein-sieg.vn' />
<meta property="og:title" content="Jetzt zählt nur noch ein Sieg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dev.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/sport/2013/01/24/jetzt-zahlt-nur-noch-ein-sieg.vn" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Erstes Heimspiel in der Quali-Runde für Dornbirn – Znojmo hat man noch nie geschlagen." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://dev.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/2013/01/Bis-jetzt-konnten-die-Znojmo-Cracks-Luci.jpg" /><meta name="description" content="Erstes Heimspiel in der Quali-Runde für Dornbirn – Znojmo hat man noch nie geschlagen." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Jetzt,zählt,nur,noch,ein,Sieg" />
```

As this feature worked flawlessly until a couple of weeks ago and still does on the development system I'm out of ideas what could be the reason for this misbehavior.

Comment: I just tried it and it works great.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderNenkov for testing it. Now I'm even more confused, than I was before, because now it works for me as well. So this might have been a bug on Facebook's side?

Comment: Then again, if I try with a different URL (http://www.vorarlbergernachrichten.at/politik/2013/01/24/sorge-ums-wasser-steigt.vn) I get the same behavior as before.

Answer (score 1):

It's really strange but it seems the problem is with the cached Facebook data. The 2nd url you provided in the comments gives "You have to login to read the article". 
Sharing it on facebook gave an image and after clicking on the link there was a content.

After that I passed it through the debugger and the image changed. Sharing it after that gave the new image.

In any case you have some errors on the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and maybe you should start with fixing them. 
And additionally check why directly accessing the page requires a login.

Do you use HTTP_REFERER or something like that?

Comment: The login form is OK, because the page has to reside behind a paywall.  When the page is shared to facebook, twitter or G+ and the user comes from one of those sites (by checking the Referer) the page can be displayed. This same behavior is active on both the development system (where it seems to always work) and the live environment (where it fails sporadically). I'll look into the warnings the debugger gives, thanks.